# How to update trigger for this logic?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Table1 : Userinfo_attarea

```
    employee_id area_id
          13    61
          14    61
```

Table2 : Userinfo

```
userid  badgenumber
   14   ST021
   15   ST013
```

Table3 : DevicePersonnelarea

```
areaid  areaname
  18    PROJECT119
  15    PROJECT108
```

Table4 :employee_attarea

```
emp_code    area_id
  ST021     119
  ST013     108
```

I am using following triggers it works fine but when i update multiple it changes to single value only.. if value already present means it will update otherwise insert multiple for same employee_id.
mY tRIGGER query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TimeVision7]
   ON [dbo].[employee_attarea]
   FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets FROM
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @areaid int;
    DECLARE @areaname nvarchar(50);
    DECLARE @count int;
    DECLARE @employee_code nvarchar(100);
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted) BEGIN

        SELECT @areaname = i.area_id
        FROM  inserted i
        SELECT @areaid = areaid;

        FROM DevicePersonnelarea d
        WHERE d.id = @areaname
        SET @areaid = @areaid; --Why is this here? you're setting the value of a variable to the value fo the same variable.

        SELECT @employee_code = i.emp_code
        FROM inserted i;

        SELECT @employee_code = userid
        FROM BioTime_Production.dbo.userinfo u
        WHERE u.badgenumber=@employee_code;

        SET @employee_code = @employee_code; --Why is this here? you're setting the value of a variable to the value fo the same variable.

        SELECT @count = count(*)
        FROM BioTime_Production.dbo.userinfo_attarea u
        WHERE u.employee_id = @employee_code;

        IF (@count=1) BEGIN
            UPDATE  BioTime_Production.dbo.userinfo_attarea
            SET BioTime_Production.dbo.userinfo_attarea.area_id = @areai
            FROM inserted i
            WHERE BioTime_Production.dbo.userinfo_attarea.employee_id = @employee_code;

        END ELSE BEGIN

            INSERT INTO  BioTime_Production.dbo.userinfo_attarea (employee_id,area_id)
            VALUES (@employee_code,@areaid);

        END
    END
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted ) AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted ) BEGIN

        SELECT @areaname = i.area_id
        FROM  inserted i;

        SELECT @areaid = areaid
        FROM DevicePersonnelarea d
        WHERE d.id = @areaname;

        SET @areaid = @areaid; --Why is this here? you're seting the value of a variable to the value fo the same variable.

        SELECT @employee_code = i.emp_code
        FROM inserted i; 

        SELECT @employee_code = userid
        FROM  BioTime_Production.dbo.userinfo u
        WHERE u.badgenumber = @employee_code;

        SET @employee_code=@employee_code; --Why is this here? you're setting the value of a variable to the value fo the same variable.

        SELECT @count = count(*)
        FROM BioTime_Production.dbo.userinfo_attarea u
        WHERE u.employee_id = @employee_code;
        IF (@count=1) BEGIN

            UPDATE  BioTime_Production.dbo.userinfo_attarea 
            SET BioTime_Production.dbo.userinfo_attarea.area_id = @areaid
            FROM inserted i
            WHERE BioTime_Production.dbo.userinfo_attarea.employee_id = @employee_code;

        END ELSE BEGIN

            INSERT INTO  BioTime_Production.dbo.userinfo_attarea (employee_id,area_id)
            VALUES (@employee_code,@areaid);
        END
    END
END
```

Expected Output:userinfo_attarea

```
employee_id area_id
  14           1
  14           2
  14          18
```

Anyone help ...

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. `select @employee_code=i.emp_code from  inserted i ` this will select only one, and you don't know which one.

Comment: The problem, here, is your'e assigning values from a dataset `inserted` to variable, which can only hold one value. Don't assign the values from `inserted` to variables, treat it as it is; as a dataset.

Comment: i don't know how to clear ..

Comment: I've just edited your code so that it's legible (as honestly, that was awful to read). I've left a couple of comments in there you might want to look at though. Now, what do you mean you *don't know how to clear* ? You can more easily see now, that in your trigger you're assigning your values to a variable. if you assign a dataset to a variable, only one value will be store. As a very simple example, consider this: `DECLARE @I int; SELECT @I = I FROM (VALUES(1),(2)) V(I); SELECT @I;` Before you run it, what value(s) do you expect `@I` to have? Now run it. Was it what you expected?

Comment: What does "i don't know how to clear" mean? Your trigger is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: I would suggest not using a single trigger for both UPDATE and DELETE when the logic needed is different. It really makes things more difficult than they need to be. But looking at your code is seems it is an exact duplicate. What is the point of that?

Comment: thanks @HoneyBadger & Larnu .. I got it